# Winforms combobox containing system color names?

Tags: winforms, combobox, color-picker

What's the easiest way to list system drawing color names in a combobox? (we don't need a full blown color picker or to see the any coloring, just the color names in black and white)

Comment: I would go with the color picker, if you're looking for 'the easiest way'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
foreach (KnownColor knownColor in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)))
{
    Color color = Color.FromKnownColor(knownColor);
    if (!color.IsSystemColor)
    {
        combo.Items.Add(color);
    }
}
```

The `!color.IsSystemColor` check excludes the "colors" that Windows uses for various UI elements (e.g. Menu, WindowFrame).

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq like so to fill the ComboBox:

```
var colorComboBox = new ComboBox();

colorComboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof (KnownColor))
                .Cast<KnownColor>()
                .Where(c => !Color.FromKnownColor(c).IsSystemColor)
                .Select(kc => Enum.GetName(typeof (KnownColor), kc))
                .ToList();
```

You can then select the color using:

```
colorComboBox.Text = "AliceBlue";
```